# caching a database into an array which refreshes every 5 minutes

Tags: java, arrays, caching, dao, dto

I need to cache a database into an array using Java, what is the best way to do this?

I need this array to refresh every 5 minutes and I need to be able to query the array.

I'm looking to use two arrays and Some form of DAO DTO implementation.

Are there any set frameworks for this?

Answer (score 1):

Some key points to make your life easier:

1. Use the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for your cached data serivce
2. Use a [scheduled executor](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2se/j2se/1.5.0/jcp/beta1/apidiffs/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutor.html) to periodically refresh the data
3. Make sure the refresh is [atomic](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) - consider using an [AtomicReference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) to hold the data

Comment: 4. Consider using an existing caching solution, such as ehcache: http://ehcache.org/ (this will deal with bullets 1-3 for you)

Comment: Kudos to you @Mathias. I will check it out.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [ehcache](http://ehcache.org/) for this, you need to configure your DAO DTO implementation to cache its results & lookup results from the cache...

you can achieve the cache refresh by configuring the eviction time (time period for the cache to be cleared).